# Calcular parâmetros da distribuição de Weibull a partir de um histograma de velocidades dos ventos usando Rstudio

Tags: r, histograma

Eu consigo calcular os parâmetros de forma e escala da distribuição de weibull, onde entro com as velocidades dos ventos e usando a função fitdistr() do pacote fitdistrplus obtenho os fatores de forma e escala.
Agora, dado um histograma qualquer de ventos numa dada região, como obter os parâmetros de forma e escala?

Ps: (1) Existe somente o histograma, onde consigo extrair as frequências de incidência dos ventos (eixo Y) e os intervalos de velocidades, bins (eixo X).
(2) Desconheço as velocidades inertes de cada coluna, conhecendo somente os intervalos.

Se possível, mostrar algum exemplo de código.

[image: HIstograma]

[Aqui os dados que estou utilizando](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gydqofa1e80rjpo/ventos.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Este problema não é trivial. Uma possível maneira de resolver ele (e que talvez não seja a melhor) é pegar os pontos médios de cada intervalo onde o histograma está definido. Assuma que a coluna `%` representa o valor real da densidade nestes pontos. Com isto, a função densidade da amostra estará estimada em alguns pontos x e y. Agora basta encontrar os parâmetros shape e scale desta função que melhor explicam ela, baseando-se na densidade teórica da Weibull. Enfim, não é algo simples.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Marcus.
Vou testar a tua abordagem.
Estou criando um programa para cálculo desses parâmetros de weibull, onde existe duas alternativas, o usuário entra com os dados de velocidades do vento da região desejada ou então fornece outros dados para o mesmo fim. Uma forma de inserção seria essa do histograma. Quais dados seriam necessários para o cálculo sem ser pelo histograma e pelos ventos ou não existe outra maneira?

Comment: Boa pergunta. De cabeça, as duas únicas maneiras que consigo imaginar para estimar os parâmetros de uma distribuição são estas duas: dados completos de velocidades do vento e histograma. Ambos vão dar a "mesma" informação. Coloquei "mesma" entre aspas porque utilizar os dados completos de velocidades do vento neste exemplo específico te fornece 182.688 observações, que é um tamanho amostral mais do que razoável. Utilizar apenas o histograma reduz o conjunto de dados a apenas 32 pontos, o que pode acabar deixando a estimação menos precisa. Mas só consigo pensar nestas duas maneiras mesmo.